# Stripe connect : card to card payment

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am using stripe connect wherein I have following user roles merchant, Service provider and service requestor. I would like Service provider and service requestor to register the cards so that once a activity is marked as done by the service requestor the payment should be send to the card on file.

Comment: this is all explained in details in the docs: https://stripe.com/docs/connect

Comment: @koopajah- Thanks for sharing the link I am unable to find if a card to card transaction can be done? Do you know if it's possible?